# Testflight - Adding app to Account/Device A removes app from Account/Deivce B

Tags: ios, testflight, apple-id

I use two iOS devices for testing:

- An iPhone XS that is signed into iCloud/TestFlight with Apple account X
- An iPhone 5S that is signed into iCloud/TestFlight with Apple account Y

But for some unknown reason I've found it impossible to have a single app associated with both devices/accounts simultaneously. When I add/accept the invite on the second device/account the app is removed from the other.

**Further details**

Within App Store Connect > Users & Groups, I have two users setup using seperate email addresses. Lets call these App Store Connect User A and  App Store Connect User B.

GIVEN:

- I invite App Store Connect User A to a given app
- Accept this invite on the iPhone XS/Apple account X

THEN:

- The iPhone XS has access to the given app and can install builds freely

WHEN:

- I then invite App Store Connect User B to the same app
- Accept this invite on the iPhone 5S with Apple account Y

THEN:

- The iPhone 5S has access to the given app and can install builds freely
- BUT when I go back to the iPhone XS the device has been removed from the app and I can no longer install any builds

WHEN:

- I then again invite App Store Connect User A to the same app
- Accept this invite on the iPhone XS with Apple account X

THEN:

- The iPhone XS has access to the given app and can install builds freely
- BUT when I go back to the iPhone 5S the device has been removed from the app and I can no longer install any builds

**Please Help**

Its infurriating. What the hell is going on? As far as I can tell, there is no association between App Store Connect users, devices or Apple accounts.

I have used each Apple account X on the opposing device **in the past** but the devices have been factory reset since then. I wonder if something is being cached somewhere that links the accounts somehow. :shrug:

Comment: Have you reached out to Apple Support on this? What did they say? I would agree with the sentiment that this should absolutely not be happening, but it's likely something only they can diagnose in their backend. If it was me and I needed an immediate resolution, I'd just wipe both devices and try again.

Comment: Are you adding the second user to external testers and not replacing the existing user?  If you remove a user in TestFlight then the app is removed from their device and they can no longer access builds.

Comment: @esqew thanks for the reply, no I haven't yet contacted Apple support. I may well do that. Appreciate the suggestion. Not sure I have the time to reset both devices.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the reply. I am adding the users to "Internal Group" > "App Store Connect Users". I am never removing or replacing any users.